# Unable to save to store in Dojo

Tags: javascript, html, datagrid, dojo

I am trying to do simple operations with dojo datagrid before I move on to complicated ones. However, I am now stuck at saving to store. I am using the code in the browser and the players data in a .json file, for convenience, I put all in the source code for now.

When I refresh the browser, the data I just saved is not updated to the json file. Why is it so? And how do I fix it?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html dir="ltr">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojox/grid/resources/Grid.css" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojox/grid/resources/claroGrid.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojo/dojo.xd.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad: true"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
      body, html { font-family:helvetica,arial,sans-serif; font-size:90%; }
    </style>
    <style type="text/css">
        .dojoxGrid table { margin: 0; } 
        html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    dojo.require("dojox.grid.DataGrid");
    dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore");
    dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore");
    dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");

    dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
        // our test data store for this example:
        var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({
          //url: 'players.json'
            data: {
              label: 'pId',
              items: [{"Player":"Wayne Gretzky","Games":"1487","Points":"2857","PPG":"1.92"},
                {"Player":"Mark Messier","Games":"1756","Points":"1887","PPG":"1.07"},
                {"Player":"Gordie Howe","Games":"1767","Points":"1850","PPG":"1.04"},
                {"Player":"Ron Francies","Games":"1731","Points":"1798","PPG":"1.03"},
                {"Player":"Marcel Dionne","Games":"1348","Points":"1771","PPG":"1.31"},
                {"Player":"Steve Yzerman","Games":"1514","Points":"1755","PPG":"1.16"},
                {"Player":"Mario Lemieux","Games":"915","Points":"1723","PPG":"1.88"},
                {"Player":"Joe Sakic","Games":"1378","Points":"1641","PPG":"1.19"},
                {"Player":"Jaromir Jagr","Games":"1273","Points":"1599","PPG":"1.25"},
                {"Player":"Phil Esposito","Games":"1282","Points":"1590","PPG":"1.24"}]}
        });

        // set the layout structure:
        var layout = [{
          field: 'Player',
          name: 'Player',
          width: '200px',
          styles:"text-align:center;"
        },
        {
          field: 'Games',
          name: 'Games Played',
          width: '50px',
          styles:"text-align:center;"
        },
        {
          field: 'Points',
          name: 'Points',
          width: '50px',
          styles:"text-align:center;"
        },
        {
          field: 'PPG',
          name: 'Points Per Game',
          width: '50px',
          styles:"text-align:center;"
        }];

        // create a new grid:
        var grid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
          query: {
              Player: '*'
          },
          store: store,
          clientSort: true,
          rowSelector: '20px',
          structure: layout
        },
        document.createElement('div'));

        // append the new grid to the div "gridContainer":
        dojo.byId("gridContainer").appendChild(grid.domNode);

        // Call startup, in order to render the grid:
        grid.startup();
        //dojo.forEach(grid.structure, function(itemData, index, list){
            //itemData.editable = true;
        //});
        var btnAdd = new dijit.form.Button({
            label: "Add",
            onClick: function(){
                grid.store.newItem({
                    Player: "Someone", 
                    Games: "1000", 
                    Points: "1000", 
                    PPG: "1.0"
                });
            }
        }, "btnAdd");
        var btnRemove = new dijit.form.Button({
            label: "Remove",
            onClick: function(){
                var items = grid.selection.getSelected();
                if(items.length){
                    dojo.forEach(items, function(selectedItem){
                        if(selectedItem !== null){
                            grid.store.deleteItem(selectedItem);
                        }
                    });
                } 
            }
        }, "btnRemove");
        var btnSave = new dijit.form.Button({
            label: "Save",
            onClick: function(){    
                grid.store.save({onComplete: saveDone, onError: saveFailed});
            }
        }, "btnSave");
    });

    function saveDone(){
      alert("Done saving.");
    }
    function saveFailed(){
      alert("Save failed.");
    }
  </script>

  </head>



  <body class=" tundra">
    <button id="btnAdd" type="button"></button>
    <button id="btnRemove" type="button"></button>
    <button id="btnSave" type="button"></button>
    <br />
    <div id="gridContainer" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
  </body>


</html>
```

The source code is also here: http://jsfiddle.net/cDCWk/

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement something server side to handle the `.save()` part of `dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore` as explained [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/data/ItemFileWriteStore.html#the-behavior-of-the-save-api).

I have modified your source code, in order for it to be a bit easier to deal with: http://jsfiddle.net/kitsonk/cDCWk/1/

Also, personally, implementing something server-side for ItemFileWriteStore might be a bit silly when you can far more easily integrate the Grid with the [dojox.data.JsonRestStore](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/data/JsonRestStore.html) or the new [dojo.store.JsonRest](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/store/JsonRest.html).

Comment: The overriding of the functions seems needed to be done on the client side? Does it mean I can override the _saveEverything to do the saving, so that it saves to the server? The concept is similar if i use dojo.store.JsonRest? Thanks

Comment: For the `dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore`, yes, you have to override the method client side and tell it how to save.  For JsonRest and JsonRestStore, no, how to send the data to the server is implied in the REST protocol, and therefore there is usually nothing to do client side, just have it implemented properly server-side.

Comment: Can i hv more details on what to do in the server side? Don't really know what to do... Thanks